# SPFx on SharePoint SSSE : custom menus not appear in document sets

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, document-set

Everything is in the title : we have deployed successfully a SPFx extension on a SharePoint SSSE, with custom menu items. Everything is fine at the library root folder, in subfolders but... menus are not visible in document sets. What can we do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: One again a message in a bottle... Nobody is using onprem spfx???